# Can I use an Update cursor with a versioned feature class which has attachments in ArcObjects .NET

Tags: arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I have a problem with my code (C# ArcObjects 10.1). We are trying to update and insert 10 - 15 rows at a time into a feature class hosted in ArcSDE 10.1 on SQL Server 2008 R2.

We have a feature class which is versioned with move edits to base and also has attachments which are photos.

I did some proof of concept code a few months back and thought I had everything working - I had tested inserting and updating a versioned feature class and inserting attachments associated with a particular feature. Looking back, I don't think I tried these at the same time - the feature class I tested inserting attachments may not have been versioned.

The issue I am facing is that my code was working fine and inserting and updating features, as soon as I added the attachment table - it stopped working and I get this error :

```
Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session     [SDE_CSO.DBO.DefinitiveList_COPY]
```

at this line :

```
IFeatureCursor cursor = featureClass.Update(queryFilter, true);
```

I am starting an edit session and edit operation before attempting this :

```
muWorkspaceEdit = (IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit)featureWorkspace;
workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)featureWorkspace;


muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMVersioned);
workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
```

I did some googleing around and found a few old posts on the ESRI forums about a similar using using ArcPy and ArcObjects which seemed to suggest that using an Update cursor will not work with a table which is involved in a relationship.

So my question is.... is this possible with an update cursor - if so how? If not can someone offer an alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried leaving off the call to workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true).  I think muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMVersioned) is all you should need.

Comment: I tried without the call workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true) and still get the same exception :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit in combination with IWorkspaceEdit:

You'll need to specify whether the featureclass to edit is versioned or not:

```
muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMVersioned);
```

or

```
muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMNonVersioned);
```