# Featureclasses with attachments: objects cannot be updated outside edit session

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

I am writing an ArcMap add-in using C# with Visual Studio 2010 and ArcGIS 10.1.
I want to add features to a featureclass in an Enterprise Geodatabase (ArcGIS Server 10.1 on SQL Server). This is my code:

```
var mapLayers = GetAllLayersFromMap();
             if (mapLayers.Count > 0)
             {

                 IWorkspace workspace = ((IDataset)mapLayers[0]).Workspace;
                 IFeatureWorkspace fWorkspace = workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;
                 IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = fWorkspace as IWorkspaceEdit;               

                 workspaceEdit.StartEditing(false);
                 workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

                 ILayer layerPunt = mapLayers[0] as ILayer;
                 IFeatureLayer featureLayer = layerPunt as IFeatureLayer;
                 IFeatureClass punten = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

                 IFeatureBuffer bufferPunten = punten.CreateFeatureBuffer();

                 IFeatureCursor cursorPunten = punten.Insert(true);

                 workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
                 workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
             }
```

When I load a featureclass that has no attachments it works fine. If I create attachments to the same featureclass and try again, it fails. The code crashes on the line where the insert cursor is created: "Objects in this class cannot be edited outside an edit session". When I delete the attachments from the featureclass it works again.

If I start an edit session from ArcMap through the Editor toolbar, I can edit featureclasses with attachments (btw: this proves that the licensing level is ok). So I tried starting the edit session from code through the IEditor interface. It fails on the same line with a COM Exception.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is not working, but here's a sample that does. Supposing you have references to the workspace and the featureclass, do this:

```
var editWorkspace = workspace as IWorkspaceEdit;
editWorkspace.StartEditing(false); // or true, whatever you want

var cursor = featureclass.Insert(true);

var buffer = featureclass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
buffer.Shape = new PointClass { X = 150000, Y = 455000 }; // not strictly necessary

cursor.InsertFeature(buffer);

editWorkspace.StopEditing(true);
```

Comment: Did you try this code on a featureclass that has attachments Berend?

Comment: Yes. Same version of ArcGIS and VS too.

Comment: Does not work for me I'm sorry to say, it is basically the same code. Funny thing though: my code works if I already have an open edit session started from ArcMap...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit in combination with IWorkspaceEdit:

```
IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit muWorkspaceEdit = (IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit)dataset.Workspace;
IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)dataset.Workspace;

muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMVersioned); //or esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMNonVersioned
workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same answer you gave at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/156843/664?  If so, perhaps we should close this thread as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: It is, both questions are basically the same: how to edit an SDE featureclass with attachments (one uses an insert cursor, the other one an update cursor). The solution also works when doing IFeature.Store().